# Set character_set_results latin1 in MySQL my.cnf

Tags: mysql

These are the default character and collation settings on MySQL 5.5.62 version:

```
  mysql> show variables like "%character%";show variables like 
  "%collation%";
   +--------------------------+----------------------------+
   | Variable_name            | Value                      |
   +--------------------------+----------------------------+
   | character_set_client     | utf8                       |
   | character_set_connection | utf8                       |
   | character_set_database   | latin1                     |
   | character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
   | character_set_results    | utf8                       |
   | character_set_server     | latin1                     |
   | character_set_system     | utf8                       |
   | character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
   +--------------------------+----------------------------+


   +----------------------+-------------------+
   | Variable_name        | Value             |
   +----------------------+-------------------+
   | collation_connection | utf8_general_ci   |
   | collation_database   | latin1_swedish_ci |
   | collation_server     | latin1_swedish_ci |
   +----------------------+-------------------+
```

I would like to change permanently the following parameters to latin1 :

```
   character_set_client=latin1
   character_set_connection=latin1
   character_set_results=latin1
   collation_connection=latin1
```

I have already tried unsuccessfully to adjust my.cnf with those values,but while restarting mysql ,the daemon does not even start.
Any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked in the logs?

Answer (score 0):

```
collation_connection=latin1
```

`latin1` is not a collation.  `latin1_swedish_ci` is.